# Why does my flyway application runs scripts in the public schema?

Tags: postgresql, search-path

My search_path is set to - mydb, gisdb, pg_catalog

Even then, my springboot flyway project runs my db migration scripts on public schema.

What am I missing?

These are three extensions in 'mydb' database - dblink, postgis, postgres_fdw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by the following query:

```
alter database oat set search_path = mydb, gisdb ;
```

Also, referred this for this fix- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/what-is-the-search-path-for-a-given-database-and-user

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Where did you place this query? Mine is in one of the versioned scripts that flyway runs.